# Proving integer inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I am having trouble proving this inequality:

For positive integers $p$, $q$, $c$, $k$ such that $2 \le p < q$:

$$
\frac{(p-1) \, p^{k-1} / \, (c p^k - 1)}{(q-1) \, q^{k-1} / \, (c q^k - 1)} \le 1
$$

Note that I have verified it empirically in code for thousands of small values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is equivalent to saying the function
$$f_{c,k}(x)= \frac{(x-1) \, x^{k-1} }{ c x^k - 1} $$
is increasing on the set of integers $x \ge 2$.

Now, extend this function to the real interval $(1, \infty)$.

You have
$$ f'(x)=\frac{x^{k-2} }{ (c x^k - 1)^2} (cx^k-kx+k-1)$$
we clearly have
$$\frac{x^{k-2} }{ (c x^k - 1)^2}  >0$$
and by [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality)
$$x^k \geq 1+k(x-1)=1+kx-k$$
thus
$$cx^k-kx+k-1 \geq x^k-kx+k-1 \geq 1+kx-k-kx+k-1=0$$

This shows that $f(x)$ is increasing on $(1, \infty)$, which proves your statement.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I will incorporate it into my proof and verify each line before accepting. It looks reasonable and understandable to me at a glance.

Comment: If there happens to be an alternative simpler/shorter answer (such as one that involves manipulating integer inequalities without calculus), I would appreciate it. I want to fully understand and internalize this part of the proof before proceeding with work that builds on it.

Comment: How does the Bernoulli step work?

Comment: @Nayuki Bernoulli inequality says: If $n$ is a positive integer and $y$ is a real number with $y \geq -1$ then $$(1+y)^n \geq 1+ny$$ Now replace $y=x-1$...

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find more information based on the full name (which wasn't clear to me before). [Bernoulli's inequality at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality)

Comment: A slight correction: The interval should be $(1, \infty)$ because $f(1)$ is a division by zero when $c=1$.

Comment: @Nayuki Yes, you are right.

Comment: Awesome. Because in my world, buggy theorems can crash computer programs. =)